# Storing number of 1's in binary representation of an int array in another array

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I want to store the number of 1's in the binary representation of some integers given in an array in another corresponding array; following is the code I am writing; but it shows the error "**Change type of 'arr' to 'int'**" 
What's going wrong?

```
public static int[] arrange(int[] numbers){
String[] arr = new String[numbers.length];
for(int i =0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    arr[i]= Integer.toBinaryString(numbers[i]);
}
int[] a2 = new int[numbers.length];
for(int i =0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    a2[i]=Integer.bitCount(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: arr is containing strings, but Integer.bitCount wants an int.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount%28int%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a String to `Integer.bitCount` method:

```
a2[i]=Integer.bitCount(arr[i]);
```

But the method bitCount(int) is not applicable for the arguments (String). Change this assingment to pass  `int` value to `bitCount`:

```
a2[i]=Integer.bitCount(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per `Integer` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), method `bitCount` requires an `int` and a `String`,

`Integer.bitCount(arr[i]);`, `arr[i]` is `String`